# Why hash function return false in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, hash

I can't login. My register function working.

Here my register

```
public function register(Request $request){
        $name = $request->name;
        $email = $request->email;
        $password = $request->passowrd;


        $mailCheck = User::where('email',$email)->count();

        if($mailCheck>0)
        {
            return response([
                'status'=>500,
                'message'=>'E posta adresi kayıtlı'
            ]);
        }
        User::insert([
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => Hash::make($password)
        ]);

           return response([

               'status'=>200,
               'message'=>'ok'
           ]);


    }
```

and my login function:

```
 function index(Request $request)
    {
        $user= User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
  
        if (!$user || !Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            return response([
                'message' => ['These credentials do not match our records.']
            ], 404);
        }

        $token = $user->createToken('my-app-token')->plainTextToken;

        $response = [
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $token
        ];

        return response($response, 201);
    }
```

and api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {

    return $request->user();
});

Route::post("login",[\App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class,'index']);
Route::post("register",[\App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class,'register']);
```

So, when I request http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register with parameters(name,email and password) record is fine. Db insert run. For example I use name=test, email=test@test.com and password=test. I see this record with hashing(password) in Users table.

But when I use http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login email=test@test.com and password=test Hash::check function return false.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `$request->passowrd` ??

Answer (score 0):

For checking purposes,

```
$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi
```

Replace the above hash password instead of an incorrect hash password on the table.
Now, the password is a password. let you check.

Comment: What does it purpose ? If your hash return true what I need to do?

Comment: If my hash return true, your password is wrong. Change your password.

Comment: My password hash comes from register function. If i change password its manually solution